# Can I legally sleep in the street in France?

Tags: france

Can I legally sleep in the street in France?

Assume my location does not perturb traffic circulation, i.e. I am on the pavement, or the road is only used by pedestrians.

Comment: Should people also assume that you're an EU citizen, don't need a visa to be in Europe?

Comment: @ChrisW yes~~~~

Comment: Pedestrian traffic is still straffic, so "only used by pedestrians" may not account for anything.

Answer (score 4):

If you sleep on the streets, you are considered a "SDF" (*Sans Domicile Fixe*), a tramp.
Legality depends on where you sleep, and in which city.

It's not illegal to be a SDF (under some conditions), but until the early 1990s it was illegal to be a beggar (*mendiant/mendicité* -- this reference, [Mendicité](http://www.affaires-publiques.com/point/gp/mend.htm), is about begging)

For instance, sleeping in a car can be legal, except if you are located in a prohibited place where you could have a fine.

Some cities have voted anti-SDF acts.

See for instance (in French):
[Dormir dans sa voiture, est-ce légal?](http://dormirenvoiture.jimdo.com/que-dit-la-loi)
and [Les précédents dispositifs anti-SDF qui ont fait polémique en France](http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2014/12/26/les-precedents-dispositifs-anti-sdf-qui-ont-fait-polemique-en-fr)

SDF in law acts: [PERSONNE SANS DOMICILE FIXE (SDF)](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichSarde.do?reprise=true&page=1&idSarde=SARDOBJT000007115620)

Answer (score 2):

There's a phone number (`115`) which you're meant to call if you're homeless (or "*sans abris*", literally "without shelter").

There are shelters organized by municipalities. It's best to call this number during the day-time. If they can't sort you a shelter you might at least get a visit in the street by a social worker or the Red Cross.

See for example [Comment aider une personne sans-abri ?](http://www.madmoizelle.com/comment-aider-sans-abri-428727) (in French) and [SAMU Social](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMU_Social) (in English).

Comment: Sans abri (without "s") ^^. Sadly, social hotels are now full almost everywhere because of the arrival of refugees.